# How to assign material to GLTF react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, object, three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber

I have managed to load a gltf object into my react-three-fiber scene. Now I want to attach a material to my model. Is it possible to use standard material on this model? Here's what I tried:

const Shape = (props) => {
const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, GLTFfe)

```
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
          color: 0xff0000, 
          transparent: false, opacity: 0.5
     });

    const object = new THREE.Mesh(gltf, material)

    return <primitive object={object.scene} position={[0, 0, 0]} />
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use standard material on this model?

`MeshStandardMaterial` is the default material when loading objects with `GLTFLoader`. You probably don't have to create a new material but just modify the existing ones.

Since a glTF asset always consist of a hierarchy of objects, you need to do this:

```js
gltf.scene.traverse( function( object ) {

    if ( object.isMesh ) {

        object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
        object.material.transparent = true;
        object.material.opacity = 0.5;

    }

} );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where would I place this function in my scene? Below const object? 

this worked for me as well, converting the file using https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx

Comment: i would generally recommend to not mutate. mutation and traversal is always an anti pattern - it will cause you headaches in vanilla dom apps as well as threejs. gltfjsx creates an immutable nested graph, you can change whatever you want in there easily without traversal. this also allows you to re-use models without cloning or re-fetching them. there's a small tutorial on this here: https://github.com/drcmda/floating-shoe/

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, it's necessary to change things after loading your gltf, convert it to jsx with gltfjsx https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx